# How do I prove |z-i|=2 with $z - i = 2\cos\theta - 2i\sin\theta $?

Tags: complex-numbers

I have the following question. It's basically my first day doing complex numbers, so I am absolutely lost here. [image]
I have read that the modulus-arg form is
$$ z = r(\cos\theta + i \sin\theta)$$
Now, in this case, I tried expanding the equation given (I'm only on part i right now) and got:

$$z - i = 2\cos\theta - 2i\sin\theta $$
What do I do now?
Yes, I can factor the 2 out, but my issue is that I was told that the value of r and the signs of cos and sin must be positive for the mod-arg form. I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: If $z=x+iy,|z|=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$

Comment: $\sin\theta=\sin(-\theta)$ and $\cos\theta=\cos(-\theta)$.

Comment: $z-i=2(e^{-i\theta}) $ $\Rightarrow $$ |z-i|=2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hints:**

- For $z=x+iy$ we have that $|z|=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and use the identity $\sin^2(\theta)+\cos^2(\theta)=1$
- $|z-i|=2$ is the set of all points, $z$, in the Argand diagram with a distance of $2$ from $i$. Write $z=x+iy$ and evaluate $|z-i|=2$ to find the equation of the circle.
- $\frac{1}{z+2-i}=\frac{1}{2\cos(\theta)+2-2i\sin(\theta)}=\frac{2\cos(\theta)+2+2i\sin(\theta)}{4(\cos(\theta)+1)^2+4\sin^2(\theta)}=\frac{2(\cos(\theta)+1)+2i\sin(\theta)}{8(1+\cos(\theta))}$ by rationalising the denominator. So what is the real part?

Answer (score 1):

By definition we have that

$$|x+iy|^2=x^2+y^2$$

then

$$|z-i|^2= (2\cos \theta)^2+(-2\sin \theta)^2$$

then use $\cos^2 \theta + \sin^2 \theta =1$.